# Remember me in yii

Tags: yii, remember-me

How to Work Remember me Function in Yii.

My Coding.

In Config/Main.php

```
'user'=>array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
    ),
```

UserIdentity.php

```
public function authenticate() {
    $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
    $user = User::model()->find("username = :username or email=:username", array(":username" => $this->username));
    if ($user === null) {
        $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_INCORRECT_CREDENTIAL;
    } else {
        if($user->is_active != 1){
                if($user->activation_token_used == 0){
                    $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NOT_ACTIVATED;
                }
                else{
                    $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_ACCOUNT_INACTIVE;
                }
        }
        else{
            $isCorrectPwd = ($user->password !== Yii::app()->mclass->encryptPwd($this->password)) ? false : true;
            if ($isCorrectPwd) {
                if($user->is_deleted == 1){
                    $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_ACCOUNT_DELETED;
                }
                elseif($user->is_active != 1){
                    if($user->activation_token_used == 0){
                        $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NOT_ACTIVATED;
                    }
                    else{
                        $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_ACCOUNT_INACTIVE;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_INCORRECT_CREDENTIAL;
            }
        }
    }
    if ($this->errorCode == self::ERROR_NONE) {            
        $this->_id = $user->id;
        $this->_isAdmin = ($user->user_type == Yii::app()->const->ADMIN_USER_TYPE) ? true : false;        
        $this->setState('user_type', $user->user_type);
        $this->setState('username', $user->username);
    }
    return !$this->errorCode;
}
```

Model Class

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->_identity === null) {
        $this->_identity = new UserIdentity($this->username, $this->password);
        $this->_identity->authenticate();
    }
    if ($this->_identity->errorCode === UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE) {            
        $duration = $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0; // 30 days          
        Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity, $duration);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Whats Wrong in my code,Why Remember me not working.

And Also what is the difference between browser remember me and in that site remember me in yii.once i remember me checked and then login and also logout site.Again i run the login url mean both username and password are placed i am right?

Comment: your config file is missing identity class configuration. something like that
    'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\components\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,

Comment: please 
post complete model and view code